# Calculus as a structure in the sense of Model theory

Tags: calculus, logic, education, model-theory

I am not a specialist in Logic (my field is Functional Analysis), so excuse me my ignorance.

I suppose there must be texts where [Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus) is presented as a structure in the sense of [Model theory](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Model_Theory_An_Introduction.html?id=QieAHk--GCcC&redir_esc=y). I mean, one can construct a first-order language $\mathcal L$, where functional symbols are usual algebraic operations + symbols of elementary functions like $\sin$, $\cos$, $x^y$ in intuitively clear sense (in the case where the domain of the function does not coincide with $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^2$, the corresponding symbol should be understood as a relation symbol, not as a functional symbol). And after that one can construct an *$\mathcal L$-structure* with $\mathbb R$ as a universe. If we add two  supplementary operations, a *formal derivative* and a *formal integral* into the language $\mathcal L$, then this construction would be a *formal definition of Calculus* (I believe).

So I want to ask,

> can anybody recommend me a paper or a book where Calculus is described in this way?

I am asking this for teaching, not for research, and I would appreciate any help, not necessarily references, but any advice as well. Thank you.

Comment: I believe [Pete L. Clark](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark) has some notes where he introduces integration axiomatically, if that interests you.

Comment: I am dreaming of reading them. :)

Comment: Realize, though, that the language you describe extends first-order logic in a significant way, so standard model theoretic results may not apply. Your formal derivative and formal integral operators are a new kind of creature: each takes a variable and a term, binds the variable and creates a new term. That's more a 2nd-order than a 1st-order notion.

Comment: Brian, yes, I understand that these supplementary operations, derivative and integral, are something new in constructions of that kind. However, I believe somebody considered this already, and can clarify the details...

Comment: For a rigorous presentation that **do not** consider *derivative* and *integration*, you can see Stephen Simpson, [Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bR0ux84nSQcC&pg=PR6) (2nd ed - 2009), **Development of Mathematics within Subsystems of $Z_2$ : Ch.II**.

Comment: @BrianO, if we narrow the list of elementary functions, will it be still possible to present this as a 1st-order notion? Say, if only polynomials will be elementary functions, will it be correct?

Comment: (Yes, +1 for the reference to *Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic*. You can see there how basic and derived notions of analysis can be developed in a 2nd-order system, though the focus of the book goes well beyond that.)  Certainly you won't want distinct function constants for each polynomial, even with only rational coefficients – that's clearly a bad approach. So polynomials have to be terms, built up from variables, constants, $+$ and $\times$, and it's those things you want to apply the derivative & integration ops to. So it seems that those operators are inevitably lambda-like.

Comment: Even if this is inevitably a 2nd order construction, there must be a "scientific explanation" of the observed picture. :) Is it possible that nobody tried to look at Calculus from this point of view?

Comment: It seems your idea is intermediate in strength. It exceeds first order logic; it can be interpreted in 2nd order logic, but it doesn't quantify over sets or functions. I'd say a lot of people have looked at formalizing calculus, going back to *Principia Mathematica* (not Newton's!). Arguably, the "natural" setting is 2nd or even 3rd order logic. Simpson's book shows how you can stay low in the type hierarchy by using a pairing function and much ingenuity. I wouldn't be surprised if other approaches have appeared in mid-20th C issues of Journal of Symbolic Logic.